# Как получить через рефлексию описание полей анонимного типа параметра обобщенного класса

Tags: c#, generics, рефлексия

Есть результат выполнения запроса `IQueryable<a>`, где `a`-анонимный тип созданный в инструкции `select`.

Как через рефлексию добраться до описания свойств/полей этого анонимного класса для их последующего вывода?

Comment: Select и создание анонимного типа в вашем коде происходит или на стороне? Если в вашем, то можно, например заменить анонимный тип на конкретный или задать полям анонимного типа имена и работать по именам. Если на стороне, то немного сложнее.

Comment: проблема решена. спасибо всем откликнувшимся. Меня устроили все 3 варианта. Даже тот, который критиковал Pavel Mayorov за то, что в некоторых случаях он неприемлем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы получили обьект с ф-ции f(x), получить вложеный в <> тип можно так:

```
object test = f(x);
Type t = test.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]; /*Первый вложеный "аргумент"*/
```

это упрощённый ответ, который подходит для простых обверток которые не унаследованы

Comment: Неверное решение. Тип, реализующий интерфейс `IQueryable<T>`, не обязан быть обобщенным.

Comment: Ответ же получается используя это решение, и по просьбе автора через рефлексию, и работает для всех кто с <>

Comment: Написать вам библиотеку, на которой ваше решение упадет? :)

Comment: Вопрос был из типа<a> достать а. Да, можно не вкладывать в IQueryable а. Тогда давайте сменим саму формулировку вопроса. Может я хочу из List Dictionary и всех других существующих достать из <> сам тип a. Я считаю что для даного случая ответ верный, и он подходит для других обвёрточных интерфейсов.

Comment: Вот вам пример с `List<bool>`: https://ideone.com/v8GRys Как видно, даже в таком простом случае достать тип элемента не просто.

Comment: @nick_n_a: Проблема в том, что `test.GetType()` выдаёт не `IQueryable<a>`, а _настоящий_ тип, который может быть вовсе каким-нибудь `MyIQueryableImpl` или там даже `MyIQueryableImpl<b>` для другого `b`.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov  я с вами согласен что для общего случая нужно сканировать вложеные классы на <>, и само правильно найти подходящий как написал **VladD**. Но в 99% случаев никто хитро не обварачивает так переменные. Для библиотеки моё решение не подойдёт, а для частного случая когда просто без вложений используются обвёртки - подходит.

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь свойством [`IQueryable.ElementType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.iqueryable.elementtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Для начала, если у вас есть сам анонимный тип (переменная типа `Type`), из него легко получить нужное. Для анонимных типов компилятор использует открытые `readonly`-свойства, так что подойдёт такой код:

```
foreach (var p in anonymousType.GetProperties())
    Console.WriteLine($"Name = {p.Name}, type = {p.PropertyType}");
```

Если, например, наш анонимный тип имеет такой вид: `new { Length = 100, Date = DateTime.Now }`, то цикл выведет

```
Name = Length, type = System.Int32
Name = Date, type = System.DateTime
```

---

Осталась проблема того, как получить сам анонимный тип. Хорошее решение изложено в ответе @Pavel Mayorov. Вот ещё одно решение, с насилием над типовыводителем:

```
static Type GetInnerType<T>(IQueryable<T> iface) => typeof(T);
```

---

Для случая, когда ваш объект реализует на самом деле *несколько* интерфейсов `IQueryable<T>`, метод `GetInnerType` применить не удастся (компилятор не знает, к какому из интерейсов делать upcast), так что нужен более сложный код с рефлексией:

```
typeof(C).GetInterfaces()
         .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>))
         .Select(i => i.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
```

Проверка:

```
class B : IQueryable<decimal>
{
    public Type ElementType { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    public Expression Expression { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    public IQueryProvider Provider { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    public IEnumerator<decimal> GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

class C : B, IQueryable<int>, IQueryable<string>
{
    Type IQueryable.ElementType { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    Expression IQueryable.Expression { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
    { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator() {throw new NotImplementedException();}
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var t in 
        typeof(C).GetInterfaces()
                 .Where(i => i.IsGenericType &&
                             i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>))
                 .Select(i => i.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
        Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

выдаёт

```
System.Decimal
System.Int32
System.String
```

Как из типа-аргумента получить список полей и их типов, смотрите в начале ответа.

Comment: typeof - Разве рефлексия :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Согласен — подправил.